# Custom SkipLine whilst reading a file vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have written some vba code to read in a text file however there are no carriage returns or tab's to delimit the file I am reading.

I am using MS Access and inserting each line of the file into my database which works when I manually put a carriage return in my text file however when the data is received it is not in this required format.

For Instance the data is currently like

```
Record115022017ABCDRecord216022017DCBA
```

I want the data to be :

- Line 1 : Record1 15022017 ABCD
- Line 2 : Record2 16022017 DCBA

Code :

```
Dim file As String

file = ("C:\data.txt")

Open file For Input As #1

i = 1

While EOF(1) = False

Line Input #1, strLine


DATABASE INSERT STATEMENT

**Start reading New Line of File**

i = i + 1


Wend
Close #1
```

So I just need help to replace the text **Start reading New Line of File** with valid code. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the line into two using Mid:

```
s = "Record115022017ABCDRecord216022017DCBA"
l1 = "Line" & Str(i) & ": " & Mid(s, 1, 6) & " " & Mid(s, 7, 1) & " " & Mid(s, 8, 8) & " " & Mid(s, 16, 4) 
l2 = "Line" & Str(i + 1) & ": " & Mid(s, 20, 6) & " " & Mid(s, 26, 1) & " " & Mid(s, 27, 8) & " " & Mid(s, 35, 4)
```

which will output two lines:

```
Line 0: Record 1 15022017 ABCD
Line 1: Record 2 16022017 DCBA
```

Adjust your loop to let i Step 2.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion however I cannot use this solution as the data is not always in the same format. There may be different types of record in the file which I need to account for. i.e. 

`Record115022017ABCDRecord216022017DCBARecord315022017ABCD23042016`

Where the third record contains an extra value. There is also no defined structure on which record will come after another. I was hoping there is some way to open the file again starting at a specific character

Comment: There is. Read it as binary and not line by line. But that is only useful if you know how many bytes (characters) you want to read. So your only option is to read line by line and then parse these to split them into multiple records.

Comment: Hi @Gustav I managed to get it working using a binary read of the file using the Seek command. 

I could have explained better the contents of the file but I have got a solution thanks to your suggestion above.

Basically there are a number of different record types in the file however each record type has a defined length. I was able to use an IF statement to check the first two characters(which define the record type) and a new variable j which I increment by the record length to successfully read the file.

Many thanks

Comment: Great! Thanks for the feedback.